# Iranian citizen with Hungary permanent residency

Tags: visas, residency, iranian-citizens

I am an Iranian citizen with permanent residency in Hungary.

1. Can I travel to non-Schengen countries like Romania, Bulgaria, Montenegro, Serbia, etc?
2. Can my children study in another European country?
3. Can I travel to the UK only with my Iranian passport and PR card?

Thank for your answers.

Comment: Thanks for your answeres, What about travelling to none Schengen Courtney , But European like Romania & Bulgaria
Also Is it possible to me to work in other European country? Is it difficult or just need to meet the work organisation in that country?
thanks

Comment: if you have other questions, it's best to post them as new questions.  See the [help] for more info.

Comment: @davood, you will need a visa to visit. Being a PR will make it more likely that the request will be granted, but you will have to make an application. Being allowed to work is much more difficult, ask on Expatriates Stack Exchange.

Answer (score 2):

1. You'll probably need a visa -- that depends on the particular country. There are no rules that apply in general to "non-Schengen countries" as a group.
2. Not without particular permission from the country in question. Having a residence permit for Hungary does not even allow *you* to settle in other Schengen countries for periods exceeding the 90/180 day limit; it certainly doesn't magically give your *children* wider rights than that.
3. No. You'll need a visa to enter the UK.

Comment: If the question's use of "permanent residency" means that the OP is a "long-term resident" for the purpose of [Directive 2003/109/EC](https://eur-lex.europa.eu/legal-content/EN/TXT/?uri=CELEX:02003L0109-20110520) then his children probably are too, in which case your point 2 may be incorrect.